# Detecting which layout is loaded depending on the display size?

Tags: android

I have an activity that has two layouts one in the folder `layout` and the other one in
`layout-large`, (one is for the phone factor and the other one for the tablet form). How 
do I detect which layout is being loaded since in the tablet form I display more data?

Thanks

EDIT:
I know that in the tablet it will load the `layout-large` but how do I know that I am running in something with a tablet form factor?

Comment: even more: xlarge! And, since Android 3.2 there's even more qualifiers that directly approach the available screen width and/or height, so it will get even more complicated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach would be to keep a Text view with visibility set as GONE. Keep text  property for each layout different. In your code check for this view and identify which layout has been loaded.

Comment: Cool, yeah that would work ;) a bit of a hack, but a good one!

Comment: This hack sure is nice, but it would nevertheless be nice to know how to do it without "hacking". There must be a way...

Answer (score 10):

You can detect it programmatically:

```
(getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
```

and with other methods and properties in getResources().getConfiguration()